# Splitting records which has | delimiter

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I'm having a two columns say Value column is having records like `'abc|comp|science|raja'` and I want to split this records like `abc,comp,science,raja` and I need to compare it with another column say `CHECKER` which is having record as science

## Value

```
abc|comp|science|raja
```

## Checkers

```
science
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to split the string and you don't even need a regular expression; just check whether the `checker` string (with leading a trailing delimiters) is a sub-string of `value` (with leading and trailing delimiters):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value, checker ) as
  SELECT 'abc|comp|science|raja', 'science' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc|def|ghi',           'xyz'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc',                   'abc'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abcdef',                'abc'     FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  '|' || value || '|' LIKE '%|' || checker || '|%';
```

**Output**:

> ```
> VALUE                 | CHECKER
> :-------------------- | :------
> abc|comp|science|raja | science
> abc                   | abc
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d6fa7b290a28476c5ca483d67c35ebd9)*

Comment: Definitely the least computer science-y solution presented, and all the better for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your pipe delimited string in individual values and represent that as a table. Then you can just join to your Checkers table.
The web is full of examples, here are 2 ways to do it.

1. The REGEXP way...

```
WITH test_tab AS 
(SELECT 'abc|comp|science|raja' str FROM dual  
)  
SELECT regexp_substr (str, '[^|]+', 1, rownum) split  
  FROM test_tab  
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (regexp_replace (str, '[^|]+'))  + 1;
```

2. If you have Application Express in your database, you can use apex_string to do the magic for you:

```
SELECT
  column_value
  FROM
  TABLE(apex_string.split(
    'abc|comp|science|raja',
    '|'
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, value, checkers) as
  2    (select 1, 'abc|comp|science|raja', 'science' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'xyz|bla|nothing'      , 'zzz'     from dual
  4    )
  5  select t.id,
  6         regexp_substr(t.value, '[^\|]+', 1, column_value) val,
  7         column_value rn,
  8         t.checkers,
  9         --
 10         case when regexp_substr(t.value, '[^\|]+', 1, column_value) = t.checkers then 'Match'
 11              else 'No match'
 12         end what
 13  from test t cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 14                                             connect by level <= regexp_count(t.value, '\|') + 1
 15                                            ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 16  order by t.id, rn;

        ID VAL                           RN CHECKER WHAT
---------- --------------------- ---------- ------- --------
         1 abc                            1 science No match
         1 comp                           2 science No match
         1 science                        3 science Match
         1 raja                           4 science No match
         2 xyz                            1 zzz     No match
         2 bla                            2 zzz     No match
         2 nothing                        3 zzz     No match

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to check whether the checker is in the value, in that case you can do this:

```
    with mytable as 
( select 'abc|comp|science|raja' value
       , 'science' as checker
    from dual
   union all
  select 'science|abc|comp|raja'
       , 'science'
    from dual
   union all
  select 'abc|comp|raja|science'
       , 'science'
    from dual )
select x.value
  from mytable x
 where regexp_like(value, '(^|\|)' || checker || '($|\|)')
```

The regex_like is searching inside the value for the checker with either a pipe or the end of the string, so it will match the keyword at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of the string. But it would not match "sciences".

Alternatively if you want to see all the rows and check whether they passed the "check" you could do:

```
    with mytable as 
( select 'abc|comp|science|raja' value
       , 'science' as checker
    from dual
   union all
  select 'science|abc|comp|raja'
       , 'science'
    from dual
   union all
  select 'abc|comp|raja|science'
       , 'science'
    from dual
   union all
  select 'abc|comp|raja|sciences'
       , 'science'
    from dual )
select x.value
     , x.checker
     , case when regexp_substr(value, '(^|\|)' || checker || '($|\|)') is not null 
            then 'Y' 
        end as passed
  from mytable x
```